# Python selenium function driver.execute_script() won't execute my code in the script?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, execute-script

In my python script I use selenium function `driver.execute_script()` which won't execute all code in the script. Specifically, one code works but others not.

**This code works:**

```
driver.execute_script("""
        let w = window.open("{}","_blank");
        w.console.log("asdf");
        """.format(link))
```

**But this here didn't work:**

```
driver.execute_script("""
        let w = window.open("{}","_blank");
        w.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
            w.console.log("asdf");
        });
        """.format(link))
```

I need this event listener because the body of this function will work with DOM elements, but when I type code with an event listener python just skip executing the script, WHY? :(

Comment: first you could print generated string and use it directly in JavaScript in browser. Other problem can be that browser can remove this code from memory when you (re)load page.

Comment: don't you get error when you run in console/terminal? When you use `format()` then `{...}` has special meaning in string - `open("{}"` but also in `function () {...}` - and you have to use `{{ }}` to use it as normal `{ }` - `function () {{....}}`

Comment: Yes, you're right! curly braces were a problem. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `format()` then `{...}` has special meaning in string - not only in `open("{}"` but also in `function () {...}` - and you have to use `{{ }}` to use it as normal `{ }` -

```
function () {{....}}
```

---

More on [PyFormat](https://pyformat.info/)